# CKEditor and JQuery Validation: error message not disappearing after entering text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, jquery-validate

The JQuery validation error message is not disappearing even after entering text in CKEditor.

**Fiddler:** http://jsfiddle.net/BmZ93/458/

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add-job').validate({
    ignore: [],         
    rules: {
                editor1: {
                    required: function() 
                    {
                      CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();
                    }
                  }
                },
                messages: {
                Job_Title: "Required",
                Job_Location: "Required",
                jobid: "Required",
                Job_Cat: "Required",
                editor1: "Required"
                },
                /* use below section if required to place the error*/
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
                {
                    if (element.attr("name") == "editor1") 
                    {
                       error.insertBefore("textarea#editor1");
                    } else {
                       error.insertBefore(element);
                    }
                }
            });
});
```

[image]

**Expectation:**
Once the user enters some text in ckeditor, the validation error message should disappear.

Any suggestion / direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which error are you referring to?

Comment: He means when the user submits an empty form, it will show the required error, and when the user types something on the CKEditor the error must go away.

Comment: added snapshot. please verify.

Comment: It doesn't show the error also when I type and delete.

Comment: Please click on the submit button at the bottom of the page without providing text in CKEditor to see the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this on your JS, it will hide the error when the CKEditor have content:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on('change', function() {    
    if(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().length >  0) {
      $('label[for="editor1"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BmZ93/460/

Comment: Why not use this answer?

Comment: Let me try this at my end,